# Vue.js lazy loading routes error handling

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

How can i handel and display lazy route errors?

Errors like: losing internet connection, network error 401 etc

```
const page = () => import('./components/page.vue').
```

Catch the error and display it.

Comment: 401 error means `your request is Unauthorized`!

Comment: Yes but my questions is how to handling the errors like 401 not what kind of error 401 is.

Comment: you should do public your resource `components/page.vue`

Comment: а вы не пробовали `try{...}catch(e){...}`?

Comment: did you tried `try{...}catch(e){...}`?